# How do I convert text from form a form field and make the browser redirect to that address?

Tags: forms, url, redirect

I want to make a client login for my clients on my webpages and I don't want to deal with a database. Is the below thought possible?

1. I create a login page (clientlogin.asp) with a form containing on a signle line text entry.
2. I create a page (kek.asp) & upload it to under http://www.site.com/
3. Give the client 'kek' as their login pass.
4. Client types 'kek' in the form at clientlogin.asp and proceeds.
5. The script redirects to http://www.site.com/kek.asp

Is it even possible?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You don't want to deal with a database? Uhhhhh …

Comment: What's stopping everyone from typing `http://www.site.com/kek.asp` into their browser?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a common approach to store the users in a database. If you don't want to use a database you can use files instead, but I think you should use a database, because that's the best parctice.